# JS - Clicking on thumbnail will display the right image

Tags: javascript, carousel, swap

In javascript only, no librairies, I am trying to create a carousel.
I have 2 items:

- One div for the main image and the caption (the images and captions are loaded dynamically one by one after a setTimeOut)
- Another one with a list of thumbnails. I'd like to upon clicking on a thumbnail display the right image and caption.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="slide">
<h2 id="description" class="title">La Slide #0</h2>
<img id="largeImg" class="car" src="images/0.jpg" width="658" height="267" alt="" />
</div>
<ul id="thumbs">
</ul>
```

and here are my functions:

```
// Function to display the images and the captions switching from one to the other
function slideshowAuto() { 
document.querySelector('div.slide').id = 'slide-' + i;
var caption = document.getElementById("description");
caption.innerHTML = data.slides[i].slide_name; 
var img= document.getElementById("largeImg"); 
img.src = data.slides[i].image_src;  

if (i < totalSlides) { 
i++;
}  else  { 
i = 0; 
} 
setTimeout("slideshowAuto()",3000);  
} 

    // Function to display the images and the captions swaping from one to the other
function swapSlide() { 
document.querySelector('div.slide').id = 'slide-' + i;          // add an id on the current slide
var caption = document.getElementById("description"); 
caption.innerHTML = data.slides[i].slide_name; 
var img = document.getElementById("largeImg"); 
img.src = data.slides[i].image_src;

if (i < totalSlides) { 
i++;
}  else  { 
i = 0; 
} 
setTimeout("swapSlide()",50);  
} 

// Function to display all the thumbnails
function displayAllThumbs() {
thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbs');
html = '';
for( i=0 ; i < totalSlides; i++) {
html += '<li><a onclick="swapSlide(slide-' + i + ')"><img src="' + data.slides[i].thumbnail_src + '" alt="' + data.slides[i].slide_name + '" title="' + data.slides[i].slide_name + '" /></a></li>';
}
thumbs.innerHTML = html;
}
```

My troubles:

- The slide content display the last variables instead of the first one.
- The clic on the thumbnails don't swap the "slide" content.

Here is [a link](http://tinyurl.com/pjs3pqo) of where I'm at...

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Help with what exactly? What problem do you experience with your code?

Comment: I only see 1 div in your HTML and no thumbs, and no clear description of the problem.

Comment: @Meiloo what about the thumbnails and the arrows left- right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The thumbnails are now working fine. I need to work on my right/left arrows so that they move the ul to show all the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

First,you used the global `i` which is changed to 7 by `function preload` and rechanged by function `displayAllThumbs`,So you got trouble 1.
Scond,you click function is `swapSlide(slide-' + i + ')`,the parameter is a variable that doesn't exsits,also your `swapSlide` doesn't accept parameter.

Change to this will solve your problem:

```
    function preload(images) {
        if (document.images) { 
            var imageArray = data.slides[i].image_src;
            var imageObjs = [];
            var imageObj = new Image();
            for(var j=0; j <= totalSlides - 1;j ++) {    
                imageObj.src = imageArray[j];
                imageObjs.push(imageObj);
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to display the images and the captions switching from one to the other
    function slideshowAuto() { 
        setSlide(i);

        if (i < totalSlides) { 
            i++;
        }  else  { 
            i = 0; 
        } 
        //document.getElementById('slide').style.webkitTransition = 'opacity 1s';
        setTimeout("slideshowAuto()",3000);  
    } 

    // Function to display the images and the captions swaping from one to the other
    function swapSlide(index) { 
        i=index;  //change the current i
        setSlide(index);
    } 

    // Function to display all the thumbnails
    function displayAllThumbs() {
        thumbs = document.getElementById('thumbs');
        html = '';
        for( var k=0 ; k < totalSlides; k++) {
            html += '<li><a onclick="swapSlide(' + k + ')"><img src="' + data.slides[k].thumbnail_src + '" alt="' + data.slides[k].slide_name + '" title="' + data.slides[k].slide_name + '" /></a></li>';
        }
        thumbs.innerHTML = html;
    }
    function setSlide(index){
            document.querySelector('div.slide').id = 'slide-' +index;           // add an id on the current slide
            var caption = document.getElementById("description"); 
            caption.innerHTML = data.slides[index].slide_name; 
            var img = document.getElementById("largeImg"); 
            img.src = data.slides[index].image_src;

    }
```

And can i get accepted?
I add a new function to avoid the repeat.

Comment: Now to wrap this up nicely, I'd like to if I can make my code better and avoid the code repetition: 
    var caption = document.getElementById("description"); 
    caption.innerHTML = data.slides[index].slide_name; 
    var img = document.getElementById("largeImg"); 
    img.src = data.slides[index].image_src;
Any great ideas?

Comment: @Meiloo I add a new function belowto avoid the repeat.